# Directed Hamiltonian Reduction

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

The reduction function given by Richard Karp in '*Reducibility among combinatorial problems*' for **Directed Hamiltonian Cycle** $\leq_{p}$ **Undirected Hamiltonian Cycle** goes as follows :

for input $G = (V,E)$, return $G' = (N, A)$ where

$N = V $ x $ \{0,1,2\}$
$A = \{ \hspace{5pt} \{ \langle u,0 \rangle,\langle u,1\rangle \}, \{ \langle u,1\rangle, \langle u,2\rangle \}\hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt} u \in V \} \cup 
\{ \hspace{5pt} \{ \langle u,2 \rangle,\langle v,0\rangle \} \hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt} \langle u,v \rangle \in E \} $

Why do we need the $\langle u, 1 \rangle$ vertices between $\langle u, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle u, 2 \rangle$ ?

Thanks!